# file_put_contents appending rows to a CSV file in PHP

Tags: php, file-put-contents

If I have a CSV file with 5000 rows on my server, does file_put_contents read the whole file into memory before appending a new row?

I have a custom tracker PHP script that appends one line to a server side CSV file each time a new web visitor comes.

With 100 or so visitors, the CSV file is small, and the script is fast.

But with high numbers - I am wondering if my PHP script will slow down when appending a new row?

Thanks

Comment: Look here for performance about file_put_contents: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23882138/php-file-put-contents-performance-on-750-thousand-lines-text-files

Comment: I would advise creating an archive of the file every day or so, depending on your web traffic. You could use filesize limitation, like the OP of the thread I just posted above.

Comment: Thanks will check the links